# Javascript Linear Search duplicate array

Tags: javascript

```js
function hasDuplicateValue(array) { 
  var steps = 0;
  var existingNumbers = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    steps++;
    
  if(existingNumbers[array[i]] === undefined) {
    console.log(existingNumbers);
    existingNumbers[array[i]] = 1; 
    } 
    else {
    return array[i];
    }
  }
  
  return false; 
}

hasDuplicateValue([1,10,2,3])
```

I don't understand how javascript is allocating space in the array for undefined. Or how inside the **for loop** javascript places the '10' of the input argument array in the 11th index. Curious about what is going on under the hood. I've never seen javascript behave like this.

Answer (score -1):

Just think about what is happening at each stage and it all makes perfect sense.

In the first pass of your for loop, your if statement resolves to be

existingNumers[array[i]] === undefined, since i=0 at this time

existingNumers[array[0]] === undefined, since array[0]=1

existingNumbers[1] === undefined

Since this is true, you log existingNumbers which you have defined as an empty array. So the first console.log event is "[]". Then below that you set existingNumber[1] = 1. Since you haven't set existingNumber[0], it is undefined.

In the second loop, your if statement resolves to be

existingNumers[array[i]] === undefined, since i=1 at this time

existingNumers[array[1]] === undefined, since array[1]=10

existingNumbers[10] === undefined

Since that is also true, you log existingNumbers which is currently [undefined, 1]. Then you set existingNumber[10] = 1. All other elements from existingNumbers[2] to existingNumbers[9] are undefined.

In the third loop, your if statement resolves to be

existingNumers[array[i]] === undefined, since i=2 at this time

existingNumers[array[2]] === undefined, since array[2]=2

existingNumbers[2] === undefined

Since that is also true, you log existingNumbers which is currently [undefined, 1, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1]. Then you set existingNumber[2] = 1, changing it from where it was undefined previously.

In the fourth loop, your if statement resolves to be

existingNumers[array[i]] === undefined, since i=3 at this time

existingNumers[array[3]] === undefined, since array[3]=3

existingNumbers[3] === undefined

Since that is also true, you log existingNumbers which is currently [undefined, 1, 1, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1]. Then you set existingNumber[3] = 1, changing it from where it was undefined previously.